# How to export wasm method from tinygo to allow spaces

Tags: go, webassembly, tinygo

I need the export wasm function to contain space, but the export fail

source file:

```
//go:export canister_query get
func get() uint32 {
    return 0
}
```

build cmd

```
tinygo build -o counter.wasm -target=wasm -scheduler=none -no-debug -panic=trap ./main.go
```

then convert the wasm file to wat fat, but the wat file doesn`t have an export  `canister_query get`  function

```
(export "canister_query get" (func $canister_query_get.command_export))
```

so I tried using underscore instead, and I can see the export method in the wat file.

```
//go:export canister_query_get
func get() uint32 {
    return 0
}
```

the new wat file contains the  `(export "canister_query_get" (func $canister_query_get.command_export))`

I suspect that the compilation check fails. Is there any way to achieve this?

the go file:

```
//go:export canister_query get
func get() uint32 {
    return 0
}
```

Export method name correctly， contain space in the name

```
(export "canister_query get" (func $canister_query_get))
```

Comment: I was almost sure you couldn't do that, but the wasm spec doesn't seem to prohibit any character in names https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/values.html#names, so your wish seems possible in theory. It seems most likely to be a limitation of `tinygo`.